# Unexpected Ruby Float behavior during multiplication

Tags: ruby

```
30.0 * 0.009 # => 0.26999999999999996
```

Does anybody know why this is not `0.27`?

Any recommendations on what to do about this?

Comment: that's how floating point numbers work. "we are float of borg. accuracy is irrelevant, you will be approximated"

Comment: please read this http://www.rails-troubles.com/2011/12/ruby-float-quirks.html?m=1

Comment: I read it. The author suggests using BigDecimal among other things. I'm now reading . What do you do in your code base if you've addressed this problem before? I'm looking at 'What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic' as well. There's also a good article comparing different languages http://itreallymatters.net/post/386327451/floating-point-arithmetics-in-19-programming#.Vl4WN3arRpg.

Comment: It all boils down to the fact that computers can't represent ***every*** float accurately in binary. Thus, arithmetic gets weird.

Answer (score 2):

Since you already found materials on the *why* subject, I will just answer the *what to do* part of the question. If you absolutely don't want to approximate, you have to use rational numbers:

```
30 * 0.009r # => (27/100)
```

Comment: I guess you mean 'rational' instead of 'real'.

Comment: `0.009r` is a Rational number, which is a subset of real numbers

Comment: @sschmeck, thanks for the correction, you are right.

Comment: That's a great idea. I'm carrying about this on the context of testing the calculations of a web app, though.